# Sorcerer/Wizard multiclass learned spells

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, sorcerer

My friend is playing a wizard/sorcerer (in a campaign I'm not in) and he's claiming this (irect quote from discord):

> you can learn any spell by either finding a scroll or copying it from another wizard
>
> you can be a level 2 wiz, 8 sorc and learn level 5 wizards spells

However, from what I'm reading...

> You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single classed member of that class. (PHB 164)

and then also,

> When you find a wizard spell of 1st level or higher, you can add it to your spellbook if it is of a level for which you have spell slots... (PHB 114)

It doesn't mention how the spellbook works with multiclassing specifically, but based on these rules wouldn't a 2 wiz / 8 sorc only be able to copy level one spells into their spellbook?

Comment: Hi there! We actually appreciate duplicates: it helps future searchers find the answers by widening the net of possible search terms that point to it. I've undeleted this so it can help in that way; have an upvote of appreciation in the meantime. :)